# how to sort an array of files in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i am reading all the files from folder `data`and i want to sort them.

```
$dir = 'data';
$all_files = glob($dir.'/*.*');
asort($all_files);

foreach($all_files as $file) {  
    echo $file.'<br />';
}
```

Code above gives me as output:

```
data/1.txt
data/10.txt
data/11.txt
data/2.txt
data/3.txt
...
```

How can i sort them so that the output will be:

```
data/1.txt
data/2.txt
data/3.txt
...
data/10.txt
data/11.txt
```

Comment: The time traveller's solution would be to consider the largest conceivable number that could be in the filename, and then zero-pad to at least one additional digit. Eg: `sprintf("foo_%06d.txt", 42); // foo_000042.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strnatcmp](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.strnatcmp.php)

```
usort($all_files, "strnatcmp");
print_r($all_files);
```

Or

```
sort($all_files, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

Or

[natsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

```
natsort($all_files);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the sorting rule to your asort line:

```
asort($all_files, SORT_NATURAL);
```